# How to call Apis in HasOffers and establish connection between server and client

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Can anyone help me explaining this to me. 
I am new to hasOffers, I want to pull offers from an affiliate and I know I have to call 3 Apis to call.
1. findAllOffer
2. create tracking url
3. call netwrok Api

My doubts are
1. we need to write a script for this?
2. Whether this is a client side script or server side script?
3. IF it is a script how to establish connection with client and server of hasOffer network?

Can any one please help, I am stuck here. Most probably writing this in either PHP or Javascript, so tagging both.

Answer (score 1):

HasOffers affiliate API is quite simple to connect with.
You should have a network_id and an API token.
That is all you need to make a request against the api for a specific affiliate account.

Best practice dictates two things:
1) your code should be server side (to protect the token) This likely necessitates a script.
2) your requests should be https (again, to protect the token)

The API is HTTP_GET only, so it should be quite easy to get started.

HasOffers has a very useful API call builder located here: https://developers.tune.com/affiliate-api/

You can test out calls using the network_id and api key, see actual responses, and play with available filters.